# В чем различия между stdin и FILE * PPP=0?

Tags: linux, c, файлы

Есть функция getc(), в аргументы ей нужно указать файловый дескриптор. Я делаю вот так:

```
FILE * PPP=0;//стандартный поток ввода
getc(PPP);
```

Но это не работает, нужно почему-то указывать `getc(stdin)`. Чем отличается `PPP` от `stdin`?

Comment: С чего вы решили, что **нулевой указатель** соответствует вообще хоть какому-то потоку?...

Comment: @Harry, например при добавлении дескриптора в набор, мне в первом аргументе нужно указать поток : `FD_SET(0,&rfds);`

Comment: О чем вы вообще? `FILE*` - ни разу не системный дескриптор файла. Корректное значение `FILE*`, соответствующее файлу/потоку, получается с помощью вызова `fopen` (или `freopen`). Нулевой указатель не соответствует никакому файлу/потоку. В принципе никакому.

Comment: @Harry, ааа, понятно)) Спасибо вам, напишите в ответ штоль, помечу галочкой:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FILE*` - не системный дескриптор файла/потока, а указатель на внутреннее представление информации о файле (в том числе и системный дескриптор). Корректное значение `FILE*`, соответствующее файлу/потоку, получается с помощью вызова функции `fopen` (или `freopen`).

Нулевой указатель не соответствует никакому файлу/потоку. В принципе никакому. Кстати говоря, при неудаче при открытии файла `fopen` возвращает именно нулевой указатель...

Comment: добавлю, что чтобы получить Си-шный поток из nix'ового дескриптора в POSIX есть функцию из `fdopen()`